# Reading less than is written in socket

Tags: c, sockets, client, buffer

Imagine a TCP server/client in C. Imagine:

1. In the server, I write 812 bytes to the socket;
2. In the client, I read only 512 bytes;
3. In the client, I write anything.

What happens to the other 300 bytes sent by the server? Are they overwritten?

Also, how could I read all 812 bytes, with a buffer size of only 512? Could I do some kind of a loop? How do I know if read() has read all that the server sent?

Comment: 1) the 300 bytes are left unread in the socket buffer until  the socket closure. They are not overwritten. 2) strange question. Of course you cannot fit 812 bytes in a 512 bytes buffer. You will have to read 512 bytes, pass those bytes to the application and come back to read the remaining bytes. 3) check [`recv ()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) documentation. It returns the number of recvd bytes, otherwise -1 on error, and errno variable will provide info about the reason (usually there's no more data), or 0 if the socket has been closed by the server.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to the other 300 bytes sent by the server?

They are still sitting in the internal buffer of the client's socket, waiting for the client's code to read them.

> Are they overwritten?

No.

> Also, how could I read all 812 bytes, with a buffer size of only 512? Could I do some kind of a loop?

Yes, that is exactly what you would have to do.  You would need to read from the socket multiple times until all 812 bytes have been read.  The read will tell you how many bytes it receives each time it is called.

> How do I know if read() has read all that the server sent?

The *socket* has no way of knowing that.  The *protocol* you implement on top of the  socket needs to dictate that.  For TCP, there are only 3 options:

1. the sender can send the data's size before sending the data itself.  The receiver can then read the size first, and then keep reading until the specified amount of data has been received.
2. the sender can send a unique terminator after sending the data.  The receiver can keep reading until the terminator is received.
3. the sender can close the connection.  The receiver can then keep reading until the closure is detected.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on if the socket is blocking or non-blocking.  Blocking will wait until data is received.
The OS will buffer a certain amount of data waiting for you to read it and once that is full the server will either block waiting for the buffer to have room or get a return of -1 EWOULDBLOCK error back.
The data that was sent will wait there until the client reads it.  Generally you want to read in a loop until you get what you need.